# How to handle HTML rendering in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, browser

Is any way to handle a WebBrowser control event when HTML page is started to render?

**Edit.** For example, in asp.net we have OnRender, OnPreRender, OnLoad, OnPreLoad events of web-page life-cycle. OnLoad in asp.net is something like Navigated for WebBrowser, the idea is to handle event similar to OnPreRender.

Comment: you want to override the rendering engine?

Comment: If you don't give enough detail in your question there's no way we can provide any help...

Comment: I'm guessing he's trying to ask if there's an event that's raised when the page is fully loaded or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle events from the DWebBrowserEvents2 Interface.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283(VS.85).aspx